# 660ti Displayport Daisy Chain no audio

Tags: nvidia, sound, multiple-monitors, alsa, displayport

I have searched the internets for this problem but could not found a solution. I have a dual monitor set up chained via display port. I have no issues with the graphical performance but I do not have sound from the monitors. It works in Windows - but I rather not use that. Anyway below is some info that I thought might help. I will provide - try whatever is necessary so please guide me on how to debug this issue.

```
Nvidia Driver 346.96

Linux xmachina 3.19.0-30-generic #33~14.04.1-Ubuntu
```

When I go to `alsamixer` the graphic card shows up and when I select it, it all goes to 0. Whatever command output you need please tell me and I will update it. That is the only thing that is not working on my fresh install and I am really excited to be close to having a linux install that works.

Update

I have added some screenshots

[image: Alsa Default]
[image: Nvidia Selected]
[image: GUI Sound Selector - No Monitor]
[image: Whole Screen]

Comment: if they all go to 0, why don't you use the arrow keys to raise the volume (above 0) when in alsamixer

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work. When I go to sound in ubuntu, display monitor and/or is not listed there.

Comment: just to be clear, I am not talking about any other menu except the controls available in alsamixer

Comment: does it say MM at the bottom of any of the channels by chance?

Comment: http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2012/04/28/how-to-fix-nvidia-hdmi-audio-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: @mchid Thank you so much for your comments. I tried them all but no luck. I added some screenshots if that helps.

Comment: Also, you should disable **automute** as it is currently enabled. Additionally, try selecting **digital output** from the pulseaudio sound menu rather than from alsa to see if that makes a difference and could it be that the volume is actually controlled by the monitor and not the  system when set to hdmi out? Finally, I seem to remember having a similar problem and the fix was to unplug the hdmi and plug it back in again.

Comment: this may help some https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

Comment: @mchid Thank you so much for your suggestions. I am at work now so it is gonna be a bit before I try those. I just wanted to say thanks and also point out that I am not using HDMI but using Displayport with two monitors daisy chained just in case it makes a difference.  Anyway. thx again